# forms authentication/web.config fix needed

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I created a webapp in 4.0 . It works /runs fine locally.

All pages should be available to all users without asking for any userId and Password.

So When I add `alllow users = "*"` Not working.

When I add

```
  <forms loginUrl="~/Form1.aspx" timeout="2880" />

</authentication>
```

And Enable forms authentication I can see form1.aspx , form2.aspx if  I type www.Mydomain/form2.aspx or www.mydomain/form1.aspx

But If I disable forms authentication or delete these lines from web.config I am not able to see form1 or form2

Now I added home.html and Index.html and When I try to open these 2 files

www.mydomain/index.html it is getting redirected to form1.aspx

Please help.

Comment: You've said `alllow users = "*"` above. Is that a typo when asking the question, or a typo in your `web.config?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` means any authenticated user, have you tried

```
<allow users="?" />
```

Comment: I am getting below error .You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to "Path"

Comment: Changing the AAnonymous Authentication from Specific user to application pool Identity solved the Issue.

Thank you.